# How to actualice the positions of the items in a googlemap?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

i have a googlemap app that displays two items (itemizedoverlay class) and i have a Update button. When i press the update button, i want to remove the items from the map, and put again the same items but with the new latitude and longitude values (i have a service that actualice the latitude and longitude fields that i have in sharedPreferences, and also i recibe the other position by a bundle)

what i am doing wrong? when i try my code, the items of the map doesn't be removed.... just new items appear... but i want to remove the old ones

```
updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mapOverlays.clear();
                updateMyPosition();
                updateFriendPosition();
            }
        });
```

and these are my two functions:

```
private void updateFriendPosition() 
    {
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();//get the intent & bundle passed by X
        userText.setText(bundle.getString("user"));
        permissionText.setText(bundle.getString("permission"));
        lastUpdateText.setText(bundle.getString("lastupdate"));
        String coordinates[] = {bundle.getString("lat"), bundle.getString("lon")};  
        lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
        p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(p, bundle.getString("user"), "Hi Friend!");
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);// dibujo la estrella con la posicion actual del friend

        mc.animateTo(p); ///nos centra el mapa en la posicion donde esta nuestro amigo
        mc.setZoom(10);  /// ajusta el zoom a 10        
    }

private void updateMyPosition()
    {
        String coordinates[] = {settings.getString("mylatitude", null),settings.getString("mylongitude", null)};    
        lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
        p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(p, "Me", "My Position");
        itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);//dibujo mi icono para mostrarme a mi
    }
```

i also tryed with invalidate() on the mapview but it doesn't works... still paint the old items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is based on the SDK tutorial. You've added two things to itemizedoverlay and the other one. You need to add a method in HelloItemizedOverlay, namely 'clear'

```
public void clear() {
    mOverlays.clear();
}
```

Call this method before you call

```
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
```

Comment: Glad that worked. Your link to your other question points back to this one though!